# music21.converter.parseFile mutates the file

Tags: python, parsing, midi, music21

These simple lines are supposed to parse midi and then show me the midi that is represented by score variable:

```
score = music21.converter.parseFile(midi_file)
score.show('midi')
```

[How midi looks before parsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acFYw.png)

[How midi looks after parsing. All the instruments that play are perscussion ones for some reason and notes are slightly different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VcHk.png)

For some reason the midi I get after parsing a midi and immedately reassembling it is very different from the pre-parsing midi. I can't attach midi, unfortunately.

I tried to find alternatives to `converter.parseFile` in the docs, but seems that I shouldn't use anything different.

Answer (score 0):

Like many programs, `music21` quantizes MIDI files when parsing them. You can disable this by calling `converter.parse` with the `quantizePost=False` argument. This might rule out a major source of the discrepancies.